# xcode 4.4.1 uialertview crash

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Whenever my app opens up, if checks for certain condition. If it fails, an UIAlertView is displayed to the users.

The build complied in xcode 4.4.1 crash, when the [alertview show] is executed, where as it works fine in xcode 4.3.2 and xcode 4.5.

Here is the code

```
    NSString *appMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error Message HERE"];
UIAlertView *appMessageAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:NSLocalizedString(appMessage,@"Error Message") delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"ok"),nil];
appMessageAlertView.delegate = self;
[appMessageAlertView show];
[appMessageAlertView release];
```

Missed an important info: The crash happens in iOS6

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertView's delgates method is called when showed or dissmissed. So add

```
 <UIAlertViewDelegate> in .h
```

Again it further crashes

```
 delegate:nil in line 2
```

then Remove

```
appMessageAlertView.delegate = self;

 [appMessageAlertView release];
```

Comment: On the removing release -- doesn't that make alloc/init unbalanced?

Comment: release is not allowed when using ARC, but this will give you a compile error. When not using ARC the release should be there.

Comment: crash != compile error. I assume, that if there's an ARC issue, it would be noticeable in xcode 4.5 too.

Comment: @Farcaller I now crash != compile error. But having `release` in ARC code will give you a compile error. So you are probably not using ARC and should therefore also don't remove the `release`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a title string.

Also your first line could be simplified to: 
`NSString *appMessage = @"Error Message HERE";`

Line 3 is also not necessary as you already set the delegate in Line 2

If you have ARC enabled `[appMessageAlertView release];` is not allowed.

Is there a reason you are using `otherButtonTitles`? Why not simple setting the `cancelButtonTitle` to `NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)` ?

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS, IT WILL WORK:

```
UIAlertView *appMessageAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Error    Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"ok",nil];
[appMessageAlertView show];
[appMessageAlertView release];
```